# Magento2 Google feed

Tags: magento2

I have 270 k product in my store. Now I want to create CSV and send to Google feed by custom script, how to achieve this in Magento2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of products , the best extension for that is **Xteno Magento Product Feed Export Module** [Link](https://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/magento-product-feed-export-module.html) . 
I have installed this , tested this and it provides the templates generated in magento 2 admin for product feed also the export as csv option in your case . You can read more on the link i showed you .